# URL not splitting into directories

Tags: php, url, explode

I have a function that explodes a URL into directories. If I visit this script at `example.com/test/directory`, it should return `test`

```
function URLPart($part) {
    if ($part > 0) {
        $url = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        return $url[$part - 1];
    } else {
        return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }
}

URLPart(1);
```

Why is this not happening? I get nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons you get *nothing*:

1. Because a function call doesn't print to screen -- `echo` does.  You need to echo your `return` value.
2. @Syscall is correct that there is a leading `/` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` so that is also throwing off your element targeting.  `1 - 1` will have you accessing the `0` element `explode()`'s array.  (I'm actually not sure why you were subtracting 1 from `$part`.)

While I am here I'll offer some additional advice.

- `$part` is expected to be an integer, but let's force that to be true with `intval()`.
- `!$part` is used in the conditional to determine if the value is `0`
- I've extended your sample path string to illuminate my next point.  I recommend adding `$part+3` as the 3rd parameter of the `explode()` call so that the function doesn't have to do any unnecessary work.  For this case, we are accessing element `2` of the array, so jamming the remainder of the path into element `3` is of no consequence.  (see demo's output for how this works out)
- Before attempting to access an array element by key, it is good practice to check that the key exists first -- to avoid a Notice.  This is the reason for the `!isset()` condition.
- `++$part` means add one to `$part`.
- I prefer to write the early returns (failures) first in my codes, and put the successful output as the lowest return.  And as I said earlier, `echo` the return value.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01e5c3cb2e1571e12d45529c96768c184a3027a6))

```
function URLPart($part){
    if(!$part=intval($part)){  // convert to integer and check if zero
        return '/example.com/test/directory/foo/bar/what'; // $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
    }else{
        $url = explode("/",'/example.com/test/directory/foo/bar/what',$part+3); // $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        var_export($url);
        echo "\n\n";
        // when $part=1, offset 2 is desired
        if(!isset($url[++$part])){  // if incremented $part is an invalid / non-existent offset
            return '/example.com/test/directory/foo/bar/what';  // change this to your needs
        }else{
            return $url[$part];
        }
    }
}

echo URLPart(1);  // you must echo the return value if you want it to be printed to screen
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => 'example.com',
  2 => 'test',
  3 => 'directory/foo/bar/what',
)

test
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable contains an initial `/`, e.g. `"/test/directory"`.

You have to `ltrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/')`, before.

```
$url = explode("/", ltrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'));
```

or just :

```
return $url[$part];
```